# Why session gets auto expired?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I faced one issue regarding Session expiration.

I have one page which redirects to another server Url I mean different than first URL. My problem is this,  when I return from my original url sometimes my session is expired. I can't get exact idea what is the reason. Is there anyone who know solution?  In my web config I have wrote this line

```
<sessionState timeout="2440"   mode="InProc"></sessionState>
```

If anyone want more detail than comment here.

Comment: @Amit Ranjan do  you know answer?? or any suggestion for me?

Comment: What time is between your two site visits?

Comment: @Herdo thanks for quick replay.. I faced this issue some time. not always

Comment: Take a look [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1731507.aspx). You might browse the linked answers in this thread.

Comment: Are you returning to URL of the same domain?

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter thanks for replay. I have used same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yuriy Galanter and  Herdo. I Got the actual result. My problem is when I start visit first page this request form

```
http://Site
```

and than second request with other site and when I return back with my site than I requested(by mistake) page to

```
http://WWW.Site
```

so problem is

```
WWW
```

I have to return with only

```
http://Site
```

. Thanks to all stack members.